# Taking formatted input using fscanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read non-numeric words from a text file, which can be separated by comma,dot,colon or quotes or some combination of this like ". The code I'm trying so far is reading non-numeric words
correctly, but leaving the delimiters.Am i using fscanf() right ?

```
int ReadWords(FILE* fp, char *words[])
{
    int i=0;
    char temp[50],tmp[50]; // assuming the words cannot be too long
    while (fscanf(fp,"%s%*[,.\":]",temp)==1) //ignore punctuation
    {
        if (isNumeric(temp))
            continue;
        printf("%s\n",temp);
        words[i] = strdup(temp);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    // The result of this function is the number of words in the file
    return i;
}
```

I am getting output like

```
emergency,"
"an
unknown
car
entered,
```

I need like

```
emergency
an
unknown
car
entered
```

Comment: Please update your question title to be more specific about the type of input that you want to distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` format scans "words", i.e. chunks of contiguous non-space. This includes punctuation.

You want to scan non-numeric words, i.e. alphabetic characters only. You could use the `%[...]` format as you already do for punctuation, for these characters:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%49[a-zA-Z]%*[^a-zA-Z]", temp) == 1) ...
```

Things to note:

- The minus sign defines ranges of characters in brackets unless it's the first or last character, so `%[a-zA-Z]` scans unaccented Latin letters.
- I've added a maximum word length of 49 in the format so that you don't overflow the char buffer.
- I treat anything except letters as punctuation. That's a simple assumption, but it divides your input neatly into letter/punctuation sequences. You can negate the letters you want to include with a caret `^` as the first letter inside the brackets.
- You should probably do a (possible empty) scan of punctuation first, so that the real scanning starts with a letter.

Comment: Thanks.. that actually cleared up another confusion I had regarding the project too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're consuming the punctuation before you get to the ignore clause.

Try: `"%[^,.\":]%*[,.\":]"`

Comment: Shouldn't there be a string specifier somewhere ?

Comment: @Stormbringer um, there are two - `%[` is a string specifier.